# How can I handle a dialog box raised by a program I start from Perl?

Tags: perl, exception, windows-xp, system

I have a Perl script that calls another application I don't have control over. I use the `system()` to call this application. On occasion, this application generates an unhandled exception and puts up an exception dialog box that needs to be attended to. Since this is an unattended Perl script, I would like to detect this situation and handle it within the Perl script and continue on. My search for solutions has not been fruitful. Since `system()` generates a child process, the standard exception handling mechanisms in Perl do not apply. I am running on Windows XP. Any suggestions?

Comment: What OS are you on?  What exactly does the dialog box say?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am on Windows XP running perl on a Cygwin shell and the application that is causing the exception is 'make'.

Comment: make is raising a dialog box? Can you show us a screenshot, perhaps? What does the dialog box say?

Comment: 'exception', I'm guessing that 'make' "caused an error and has to be shutdown", which suggests a problem larger than perl.  Perhaps fix your cygwin installation before proceeding.

Comment: Actually the dialog box is the standard Windows error reporting dialog box asking to send error report to Microsoft. The error dialog doesn't happen very often and it takes a while to get to that point so I didn't recollect the dialog in my original question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the Perlmonks post [Win32::OLE: how to call Excel VBA macros and catch all VBA errors without dialog boxes appearing?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=827995) can help.

Almost any time that you have to interact with Windows system things, you're going to end up using the Windows API (is there an official name for that?) through [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-OLE).

Answer (score 2):

Find the dialog box and kill it. For example, if you want to automatically kill a window that thas the title of Calculator, the following script should work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::GUI();

use constant WM_CLOSE => 16;


sub kill {
    my $handle = Win32::GUI::FindWindow('', 'Calculator');
    Win32::GUI::SendMessage($handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0); 
}

while(1){
    &kill;
    sleep(5);
}
```